# On the least number of factors $\sigma(q^{e_q})$ to get the least multiple of $\operatorname{rad}(n)$, on assumption that $n$ is an odd perfect number

Tags: elementary-number-theory, reference-request, prime-factorization, divisor-sum, perfect-numbers

I don't know if my question can be answered easily from your reasonings and knowledeges of the theory of odd perfect numbers. I wondered about it yesterday. Now this post is cross-posted on MathOverflow with identificator [**MO 362492**](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/362492/least-number-of-factors-sigmape-of-representation-of-sigman-to-get-th), I add this information for all users.

**Definitions and notation.** We denote the sum of divisors function $\sum_{1\leq d\mid m}d$ as $\sigma(m)$ and the radical of an integer $m>1$ as $\operatorname{rad}(m)$, the product of distinct primes dividing $m$ with the definition $\operatorname{rad}(1)=1$. Both arithmetic functions are multiplicative functions. As reference for all users I add that Wikipedia has the articles for *Perfect number*, *Euclid–Euler theorem* and *Radical of an integer*.

For integers $m>1$ since the sum of divisors function $\sigma(m)$ is multiplicative, and we know that the fundamental theorem of arithmetic provide us the representation $m=\prod_{q\mid m}q^{e_q}$ ($q$ are the distinct primes dividing $m$ and $e_q$ the corresponding exponents in this unique factorization: $m$ can be represented as product of those prime powers $q^{e_q}$ and the representation is unique, see [2]) we get that $\sigma(m)$ has the representation $\prod_{q\mid m}\sigma(q^{e_q})$ (see [1], again see the notation of the support of this finite product in previous brackects).

The following statement is obvious invoking Euclid–Euler theorem for even perfect numbers, and I add it as motivation of the question.

**Claim.** *If* $n$ *is an even perfect number, there exist* **two factors** *of the form* $\sigma(q^{e_q})$ *such that their product is a multiple of* $\operatorname{rad}(n)$.

Here again to emphasize $\sigma(q^{e_q})$ represents those generic factors in the previous representation of $\sigma(m)$.

*Proof.* We conclude it, since for an even perfect number $n=2^{p-1}(2^p-1)$ we've $\omega(n)=2$, where $\omega(m)$ counts the number of distinct primes dividing an integer $m>1$ (I mean the Wikipedia *Prime omega function*), and $\sigma(2^{p-1})$ isn't a multiple of $\operatorname{rad}(n)$ and $\sigma(2^p-1)$ isn't a multiple of $\operatorname{rad}(n)$, thus I need the product of (at least) two factors of the form $\sigma(q^{e_q})$ from the product representation of $\sigma(n)$ to get a multiple of $\operatorname{rad}(n)$. $\square$

Notice thus that for an even perfect number **the least multiple of** $\operatorname{rad}(n)$ that we can build mulitpliying factors of the form $\sigma(q^{e_q})$ from the factorization of $\sigma(n)$, is in our case (as is implicit in the *Proof*) $\sigma(2^{p-1})\sigma(2^{q}-1)=2n$.

> **Question.** I would like to know if it is feasible a discussion around what is the number (I mean the fewest number possible) of those factors of the form $\sigma(q^{e_q})$ that I need to build the least multiple of $\operatorname{rad}(n)$, where $n$ is an odd perfect number. **Many thanks.**

Here $n=\prod_{q\mid n}q^{e_q}$ is the canonical representation ([2]) of our odd perfect number $n$, compare if you need with Euler's theorem for odd perfect number, $\omega(n)$ also counts the number of all factors of the form $\sigma(q^{e_q})$. And I'm asking, how many factors  of the form $\sigma(q^{e_q})$ do I need to build the least multiple of $\operatorname{rad}(n)$, on assumption that $n$ is an odd perfect number?

I don't know if my question is in the literature, in the case that it is in the literature feel free to answer my question as a reference request and I try to search and read it from the literature.

### References:

[1] Tom M. Apostol, *Introduction to analytic number theory*, Undergraduate Texts in Mathematics, New York-Heidelberg: Springer-Verlag (1976).

[2] The Wikipedia [*Fundamental theorem of arithmetic*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_arithmetic#Canonical_representation_of_a_positive_integer)

Comment: (+1) Nevertheless, I am bit lost in understanding the purpose of this question. Is it an additional (perhaps not yet known) property that makes the existence of an odd perfect number even more unlikely ? Or just a formula related to perfect odd numbers ?

Comment: Many thanks for your attention @Peter my only motivation was when I've read a result from R. J. Levit, *The non-existence of a certain type of odd perfect number*, Bull. Amer. Math. Soc., Volume 53, Number 4 (1947), 392-396. I mean the COROLLARY, in last paragraph of the article. From here I've evoked the **Question** as comparison of what happens in the case of even perfect numbers.

Comment: (1/2) What I evoke is how many factors $\sigma(q^{e_q})$ (from the factorization of $\sigma(n)$, with $n$ an odd perfect number) I need to multiply to get the least multiple of $\operatorname{rad}(n)$. The case of even perfect numbers is easy to deduce since we are obligated to multiply the two distinct factors $\sigma(2^{p-1})$ and $\sigma(2^p-1)$ to obtain/get a multiple of $\operatorname{rad}(n)$. The $\operatorname{rad}(n)$ for an even perfect number provide us, in particular, its associated Mersenne prime.

Comment: (2/2) The comparison with odd perfect numbers is that it doesn't know any specific prime divisors of an odd perfect number (with the exception if we assume additionally one of the subcases of the theorem of Touchard), when we're  assuming that odd perfect numbers exist. In summary, I evoke my question from the definition of **perfect number and** the importance/relevance of **the divisor** $\operatorname{rad}(n)$ for a perfect number. I don't know if this question is new, or it can be dedeuced easily from the literature of odd perfect numbers. Many thanks all users again.

Comment: Let $p^k m^2$ be an odd perfect number with special/Euler prime $p$ satisfying $p \equiv k \equiv 1 \pmod 4$ and $\gcd(p,m)=1$.  A result by Pomerance, et al. (similar to that derived by Levit) is that $\gcd(\sigma(p^k),\sigma(m^2)) > 1$, thus essentially making an answer to your question to be very difficult.  (For some more information on the quantity $\gcd(\sigma(p^k),\sigma(m^2))$ and how it relates to the conjecture that $k=1$, please see this [MO question](https://mathoverflow.net/q/280897).)

Comment: Many thanks for your excellent contribution, I know that you have great knowledges about odd perfect numbers. I'm going to study it and your post in MathOverflow @JoseArnaldoBebita-Dris

Comment: No problem, @user759001!  Glad to be of some assistance.  =)

Comment: There is a pending question in [MO](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/412500), which seeks to verify my [earlier claim](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3606189/on-the-least-number-of-factors-sigmaqe-q-to-get-the-least-multiple-of?noredirect=1#comment7415552_3606189) (i.e. if indeed $\gcd\bigg(\sigma(p^k),\sigma(m^2)\bigg) > 1$, where $p^k m^2$ is an odd perfect number with special/Eulerian prime $p$), @user759001.

Comment: Great feedback @ArnieBebita-Dris , as soon I can I study the question/claim.